# How to use reverse triangular inequality to fulfil my requirement?

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, solution-verification, normed-spaces

I know these two inequalities

$$
\left\|\mathcal{B}_{\boldsymbol{w}}-\mathcal{B}_{\boldsymbol{w_\frac{\epsilon}{2}}}\right\|_{\infty} \leq J.\frac{\epsilon}{2}
$$

&

$$
\left\|\mathcal{T}_{\boldsymbol{w}}-\mathcal{T}_{\boldsymbol{w_\frac{\epsilon}{2}}}\right\|_{\infty} \leq J.\frac{\epsilon}{2}
$$

I need  to know an upperbound for $\left\| \langle B_{w_1},T_{w_2}\rangle - \langle B_{w_1,{\frac{\epsilon}{2}}},T_{w_2,{\frac{\epsilon}{2}}}\rangle \right\|_{\infty}$

**Proof**

\begin{align}
\left\| \langle B_{w_1},T_{w_2}\rangle - \langle B_{w_1,{\frac{\epsilon}{2}}},T_{w_2,{\frac{\epsilon}{2}}}\rangle \right\|_{\infty}
% &\leq \| \langle B_{w_1},T_{w2}\rangle - \langle B_{w1_\epsilon},T_{w2}\rangle \|_{\infty}+ \| \langle B_{w1_\epsilon},T_{w2}\rangle - \langle B_{w1_\epsilon},T_{w2_\epsilon}\rangle \|_{\infty} \\
&\leq \|T_{w_2}\|_{\infty} \| B_{w_1} - B_{w_1,{\frac{\epsilon}{2}}}\|_{\infty}+ \|B_{w_1,{\frac{\epsilon}{2}}}\|_{\infty}\| T_{w_2} - T_{w_2,{\frac{\epsilon}{2}}}\|_{\infty}\\
&\leq  J \frac{\epsilon}{2}\cdot (\underbrace{\|B_{w_1,{\frac{\epsilon}{2}}}\|_{\infty} + \|T_{w_2}\|_{\infty}}_{})\\
&\leq J \frac{\epsilon}{2} \left(J \frac{\epsilon}{2} + \|B_{w_1}\|_{\infty} +\|T_{w_2}\|_{\infty}\right) && As \, ||x|-|y||\le |x-y|\\
&\leq J \epsilon \cdot constant 
\end{align}

Can anyone verify if this proof is correct or not?

Comment: Could you clarify what are $||\cdot||_\infty$ and $\langle,\rangle$? I guess the former is some norm and the latter is some kind of inner product (that satisfies Cauchy-Schwartz with respect to that norm). Then yes this is correct

Comment: Okay. Thanks! got it